# PHP soapclient parameters from struct

Tags: php, soap

How do i write this into an array format for parameters?

```
struct Estimatation {
  EstimatationRequest estimatationRequest; 
}

struct EstimationRequest {
  ArrayOfString ConnectionID; dateTime EstimationDate; 
}
```

I got the above response from

```
var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());
```

My solution that did not work

```
$parameter = array("ConnectionID"=>"3456871", "EstimationDate"=>"2013-09-15");
```

Comment: `var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());` show your dump result.

Comment: This was my result: struct Estimatation {
  EstimatationRequest estimatationRequest; 
}

struct EstimationRequest {
  ArrayOfString ConnectionID; dateTime EstimationDate; 
} @Patrick Kostjens